Built pages in HTML and can't move them/convert them into React properly
Trying to turn a few pages I made in HTML into the react framework, and I am failing extremely bad. I like how the html looks like I know js/css/html but react is a pretty different beast. The github is https://github.com/icantfunction/InterestBenefitForms take a look at it, but this came down by someone requesting I make a few pages look better but the OG was built in MERN and I decided instead of making my own version without the framework to just convert my beautiful pages into react. I need some help because how App.js isn't how I want it to look and looks nothing like SecondFormPage.html.
This is App.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function SecondFormPage() {
    const [income, setIncome] = useState('');
    const [county, setCounty] = useState('');

    return (
        <div className="w-full max-w-2xl mx-auto mt-10">
            <div className="mb-6">
                {/* Progress bar and Title */}
                <div className="flex items-center mb-4">
                    <div className="flex-1">
                        <div className="w-full bg-gray-300 rounded-full h-2">
                            <div className="bg-blue-600 h-2 rounded-full" style={{width: '50%'}}></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-700">What is your household income?</h2>
            </div>
            {/* Form section */}
            <div className="bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
                <div className="bg-blue-800 p-6 flex justify-between items-center">
                    <h2 className="text-white font-semibold text-2xl">Income</h2>
                    <i className="fas fa-check-circle text-white text-2xl"></i>
                </div>
                <form className="p-6 border-b-8 border-blue-800">
                    <div className="mb-6">
                        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-base font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="income">Household Income</label>
                        <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="income" type="text" pattern=".{5,7}" placeholder="Household Income" value={income} onChange={e => setIncome(e.target.value)} required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-6">
                        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-base font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="county">County</label>
                        <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="county" type="text" pattern=".{4,15}" placeholder="Dade County" value={county} onChange={e => setCounty(e.target.value)} required />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            {/* Add this at the end of the first form page */}
            <div className="flex justify-between space-x-4 mt-4">
                <a href="FirstFormPage.html" className="w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center px-6 border border-blue-500 text-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                    BACK
                </a>
                <a href="ThirdFormPage.html" className="w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center py-4 px-6 border border-blue-500 text-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                    CONTINUE
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SecondFormPage;

this is the SecondFormPage:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Enhanced Health Form</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100 text-lg">
    <div class="w-full max-w-2xl mx-auto mt-10">
        <!-- Progress Steps and Title -->
        <div class="mb-6">
            <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
                <div class="flex-1">
                    <div class="w-full bg-gray-300 rounded-full h-2">
                        <div class="bg-blue-600 h-2 rounded-full" style="width: 50%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-700">What is your household income?</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- Form Card -->
        <div class="bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
            <div class="bg-blue-800 p-6 flex justify-between items-center">
                <h2 class="text-white font-semibold text-2xl">Income</h2>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle text-white text-2xl"></i>
            </div>
            <form class="p-6 border-b-8 border-blue-800">
                <!-- Form Content -->
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="block text-gray-700 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="income">
                        Household Income
                    </label>
                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline shadow-md" id="income" type="text" pattern=".{5,7}" placeholder="Household Income" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="block text-gray-700 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="county">
                        County
                    </label>
                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline shadow-md" id="county" type="text" pattern=".{4,15}" placeholder="Dade County" required>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Add this at the end of the first form page -->
        <div class="flex justify-between space-x-4 mt-4">
            <a href="FirstFormPage.html" class="w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center px-6 border border-blue-500 text-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                BACK
            </a>
            <a href="ThirdFormPage.html" class="w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center py-4 px-6 border border-blue-500 text-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                CONTINUE
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Originally I tried to put the html into the JSX page, but it didn't work, then I tried to add the link to tailwind but that didn't make it better which leads me to assume it could how the file is mixed in the directory and for context the app.js file is in a file ../my-react/src/App.js and the other one is in ../HTML/SecondFormPage.html so please help!

Can you specify exactly what is going "extremely bad"? Your conversion from HTML to JSX looks mostly OK to me. Except for the a href links, you should convert this to a React Router to switch between pages. Is tailwind CSS doing something strange?

so when I upload the html to a live server, I see the ideal webpage in the styles we want to use, when I run this code using npm start in my command prompt I am unable to see the styles I need to use at all. I noticed what you mentioned regarding the a href links, where would you suggest I put that, above the first div tags in the first line in the return function?

If you don't see the styles there is probably something wrong with your tailwind setup. Did you install tailwind locally? Do you see any errors in the console?
About React Router, you should probably read a tutorial, it's hard to explain in one little comment box. The point is that React doesn't use separate HTML pages for showing different content :)
